# How to do numeric comparison in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Why does the following output the else part?

```
some_value = 100

case some_value
when some_value <= 200
  puts "less than 200"
else
  puts "not less than 200"
end
```

Comment: Wouln't an `if...else` block be more readable in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`case...when...end`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression) construct uses `===` to check for a match.

Your code evaluates as:

```
case 100
when some_value <= 200 # when (some_value <= 200) === 100, which is (true === 100), which doesn't match
  puts "less than 200"
else
  puts "not less than 200"
end
```

You can omit the value after `case` to make the construct behave like an `if...else...`.

```
some_value = 100

case
when some_value <= 200
  puts "less than 200"
else
  puts "not less than 200"
end
```

Comment: How do you evaluate "<="?

Comment: simply replace `case some_value` with `case`.

Comment: @NilsLandt yes, just added that.

Comment: @4thSpace It's only part of an expression. `some_value <= 200` is evaluated to `true` first, and then it's fed to the `case...when...` expression.